# The current state of reflection in C++20

Tags: c++, reflection, metaprogramming, c++20, std

I started reading about reflection in C++20 and got quite confused. What is the current state of it, i.e. how much can we use as of now?

I've found [reflection TS](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/reflexpr) - but even the examples on this website fail to compile (on GCC11 with C++20) because the compiler cannot find "#include <experimental/reflect>"... So it's not exactly in the GCC?

So my question is: can we use anything of reflection now, without waiting for C++23? By 'anything' I mean for example querying the compiler for list of class members, names of enums etc? And by 'use' I mean in production code, not just for playing around.

Comment: [GCC's documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#tses) suggests they don't have support for the reflection TS. Googling around, it doesn't look like MSVC or Clang have implementations yet either. Keep your eyes open for C++23, I suppose.

Comment: No, there is no reflection in C++ (yet?) Of all the features we miss in C++, this is the one I personally have been missing the longest.

Comment: Ah. Reflections on reflection. If this was more meta we'd be posting on meta.

Comment: @user4581301 Do determine if we should discuss this on meta, please open a post on meta meta.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [link](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=YXIVw6QFgAI) to Andrei Alexandrescu'
talk on reflection at CppCon 2022, which addresses your main question: the proposals for reflection are still in the pipeline. Assuming the three-year timeline for the ISO committee to finalize the next iteration of `c++` (`c++26`) and then sufficient time for compilers to implement and support the approved features, we are looking at least half a decade before reflection (and insertion) appears under the `std` banner inside `gcc`, `clang`/`llvm`, `msvc`, etc.

Since half a decade is a long time for reflection under the hood, you could achieve something similar on the surface. For example, you can just build a minimal `c++20` script language for your small application to pry open the executable (not unlike `objdump`) and then you have the fabled interpreted environment (not unlike `python`) with reflection, insertion and the whole gamut of introspection.